# Pantomime and Mail Frameworks? - Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos, email, frameworks

Does the Pantomime Framework work for 10.5 or 10.6? Because when I look at the build error I get when compiling it says, it couldn't find the 10.4 sdk. If not, then does anyone know any other framework that works really well with 10.5 or 10.6, with an example?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to build on 10.6, be aware that `10.4 SDK` is available with the Snow Leopard version of `Xcode` but it is not installed by default.  You can install it from the `Xcode` installer on the Snow Leopard DVD or the `Xcode` download.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party, but this is how I got Pantomime to build in XCode 4.3.3 on Lion.

1. Go to Pantomime's `Build Settings` and search for `sdk`. You'll see three properties.
2. set the `Base SDK` to whatever platform you're building for ( I set it to 10.7 )
3. Delete the values for the keys `SDKROOT_i386` and `SDKROOT_PPC`.

Pantomime should build now.